# How can I join a nested Perl hash?

Tags: perl, csv, hash

I have a Perl hash, where I store information about LUNs. It has the following structure:

```
my %luns = (
    360000 => {
        Devices => [
            {   Major_Minor  => "8:144",
                SCSI_Address => "1:0:0:8",
                SCSI_Device  => "sdj",
                SCSI_Host    => "host1",
            },
            {   Major_Minor  => "129:48",
                SCSI_Address => "3:0:0:8",
                SCSI_Device  => "sder",
                SCSI_Host    => "host3",
            },
        ],
        DM_Device => "dm-13",
        Size      => "45G",
        WWID      => 360000,
    },
    360001 => {
        Devices => [
            {   Major_Minor  => "70:144",
                SCSI_Address => "1:0:1:39",
                SCSI_Device  => "sddb",
                SCSI_Host    => "host1",
            },
            {   Major_Minor  => "135:48",
                SCSI_Address => "3:0:1:39",
                SCSI_Device  => "sdij",
                SCSI_Host    => "host3",
            },
        ],
        DM_Device => "dm-53",
        Size      => "200G",
        WWID      => 360000,
    },
);
```

How can I use `join` to get a comma-separated list of all `SCSI_Devices`, for example, of `360000`?

Comment: @JonesK: I have rolled back your edit to the question as I didn't see a good reason for it and you added no explanation. The automatically-provided "added 22 characters in body; edited title" is far from sufficient, and your modification wasn't good English. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want a list of values for LUN `360000`, so for a start you need

```
$luns->{36000}
```

which is another hash with a `Devices` element, which has an *array reference* as a value, and `DM_Device`, `Size`, and `WWID` elements, whose values are simple scalars.

So presumably you want the list that is

```
$luns->{36000}{Devices}
```

which is an array of *references to hashes*, each of which has `Major_Minor`, `SCSI_Address`, `SCSI_Device`, and `SCSI_Host` elements.

It sounds like you want the `SCSI_Device` element, and `map` is the ideal tool to help you with this

```
my @scsi_devices = map { $_->{SCSI_Device} } @{ $luns->{360000}{Devices} };
```

That last step is a big leap, and it may help to separate it in your code. For instance, you can copy the reference to the list of devices for `360000`, like this

```
my $devices = $luns->{360000}{Devices};
```

and extract the `SCSI_Device` from each of the hashes in that array with

```
my @scsi_devices = map { $_->{SCSI_Device} } @$devices;
```

Either way, the array reference must be *dereferenced* and the required element from each hash in that array must be extracted.

To get a CSV record, *unless the data may contain commas of double-quotes*, you simply need to `join` the result of that `map`

```
print join(',', @scsi_devices), "\n";
```

**output**

```
sdj,sder
```

Although I think this falls short of what you actually need. If this isn't clear then please ask.

Comment: I used it as an one liner:
`print join(',', map { $_->{SCSI_Device} } @{ $luns->{360000}{Devices} };`

Comment: Okay, but I missed your point about wanting the result in CSV format. I've added to my solution to explain, but you must be careful if the data itself contains special characters like the comma, quotation marks, or in some situations whitespace.

Comment: That will work. It wasn't clear how varied your access to the data could be, or whether you wanted a vertical slice rather a horizontal one over the list of hashes. I'm pleased it is working for you.

Comment: @JonesK Welcome to SO.  Please remember that if this answer solved your question, to give it the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You're working with a Hash of Hash of Array of Hash.  To learn how to work with such structures, I recommend reading [perldsc - Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

In this instance, the following loop will print out each of your device lists:

```
for my $id ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %luns ) {
    my @devices = map { $_->{SCSI_Device} } @{ $luns{$id}{Devices} };
    print "$id - @devices\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
360000 - sdj sder
360001 - sddb sdij
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/b0P2CV)</kbd>